# How to add views to an itemscontrol in Prism with MEF and WPF

Tags: wpf, mef, prism-4

I have an application which, so far has only 2 views. View 1 is a list and the second is a detail view (once you've selected an item in view 1.

I've set up a region in my Prism shell and can get my modules loaded. What I want is for only module 1 to load initially. When I've selected an item from 1 then I want to navigate to 2 (which would then show up in my itemscontrol (which, by the way, is a tab control).

Problem I have is that I either get a) both views show initially in my tab control.

b) If I change the export attribute on view b's module to initialise on demand, when I click to navigate to view b nothing happens.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think this to do with me using view discovery not view injection. Think I should be using view injection. Just need to work out how to get view model 1 to call the container to create view 2. I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got around this by letting all the views be discovered but on initalisation of the view I deactivate all views accept the one I'm interested in. Of course I'm looking for a better way :)

```
foreach (var view in RegionManager.Regions["RegionFoo"].Views)
{
  if (view.GetType() == initialViewType)
  {
     RegionManager.Regions["RegionFoo"].Activate(view);
  }
  else
  {
     RegionManager.Regions["RegionFoo"].Deactivate(view);
  }
}
```

I do this after the views have been registered for disovery in that region. initialViewType is the type of view you wish to find. This assumes only a singleton of the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my code to inject a new view 2 in view 1's viewmodel. Problem I have now is that I need the new view 2 to be created by my container - don't know how to get a handler on the container in my view model.                         regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Add(new Views.ReleaseView());
                    regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", new Uri("ReleaseView", UriKind.Relative));'

Comment: Ended up exporting the CompositionContainer from my bootstrapper and then import it for use in the view model. Thanks again.

Comment: Yep I have used that technique as well. :)

Comment: @obaylis You can have the container being injected into the view model by itself. You just have to have the view model being resolved from the container.